# php, sql multiple keyword match using LIKE

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to grab rows from sql using LIKE, where the key matches key array in the column.

```
$key = '%PDF%';
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `ads` WHERE key LIKE '$key' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2");
```

This works fine and show the results but when i change my key to PDF FILES. i.e.:

> $key = '%PDF FILES%';

It doesn't show the results as in the db there is an array of keys, please look at my db column:

Here's My sql Key column:

> PDF, pdf, PDF SEARCH, pdf search, PDF
>   ENGINE, pdf

So whats the solution? how to get results if the key is pdf files?

I think it can be by splitting the key and then matches the keywords. right?

this can be done by `explode();` but how? and how to match with sql?

Answer (score 3):

When the key is `'%PDF FILES%'`, you are actually searching for the string "PDF FILES" and not some combination of the words PDF and FILES.

To achieve what you want, try constructing a query like:

```
$key = '%PDF%';
$key2 = '%FILES%';

$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `ads` WHERE (key LIKE '$key' OR key LIKE '$key2') ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2");
```

You can use various techniques with arrays and explode to construct a dynamic query with a variable number of keywords.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
$keyvalues=split(" ",$search_text);//Breaking the string to array of words

// Append the query by the keywords
while(list($key,$val)=each($keyvalues)){
if($val<>" " and strlen($val) > 0)

{$sql .= " name like '%$val%' or ";}

}// end of while
```

The trailing OR can be removed by

```
$sql=substr($sql,0,(strlen($sql)-3));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because LIKE works with only one string. You have to use more LIKE statements with OR in case you want to use wildcards.

On the other hand you can use IN which accepts comma seperated quoted strings, but it doesn't accept wild cards.

Answer (score -2):

You can not enter multiple keywords for Like in One single statement.

You can try for this it will help you.

```
WHERE key LIKE '%PDF%' OR '%pdf%' OR '%PDF SEARCH%'
```

and so on.....

Comment: You mean `WHERE key LIKE '%pdf%' OR key LIKE '%search%' OR key like ...`

Comment: I think you missed my point: I meant that you can't do `WHERE key LIKE 'val1' OR 'val2'` like you have in your answer, and `OR LIKE` gives a syntax error. You have to write the conditions in full: `WHERE key LIKE 'val1' OR key LIKE 'val2'`.

Comment: It's still wrong. `OR LIKE` is never allowed, you have to write `OR key LIKE` every time.

Comment: Ok i have checked in Mysql...now above query run fine...you just need to put as above for keywords

Comment: I don't want to sound like a broken record, but you really really need to repeat the `key LIKE` every time. The new query runs without errors, but *it doesn't return all the rows*. Each condition between ORs is independent, so your query is functionally equal to: `WHERE '%PDF SEARCH%' OR '%pdf%' OR key LIKE '%PDF%'`. You can probably see from that that it won't work. *You need complete conditions every time.*

Comment: As Per my knowledge we don't have to repeat Like Keywords Please check in mysql or Phpmyadmin or whichever GUI client you are using it.

Comment: I did, and *it didn't work*. (Also note that LIKE is case insensitive by default. If you tried `WHERE key LIKE '%PDF%' OR '%pdf%'` it *looks like* it works. Add a value that has the word "search" in it and does not contain "pdf" and try `WHERE key LIKE '%pdf%' OR '%search%'` and I guarantee you don't get the row with "search" in it.)